# ¿Se puede guardar una lista en SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, imagen

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.android.
En esta App el usuario completa un formulario y tiene la opción de tomar una foto. Al finalizar to, se guarda un registro en una base de datos SQL Server de este formulario y también guardo la foto en la base de datos.

En la tabla de la base tengo un campo de tipo `Image` que es donde guardo la foto que tomó el usuario. Pero quiero saber si hay forma de poder guardar más de una imágen (ya sea una `List<Image>` o un `Image[]`) en la base ya que así me lo pidió mi cliente y quiero ver si puedo simplificarlo en lugar de tener que generar más de un campo de tipo `Image`.

Comment: Las bases de datos guardan datos, no guardan estructuras. No puedes guardar una lista, pero puedes guardar su contenido.

Comment: No te recomiendo subir toda la imagen a la bd de datos , puedes guardarlo en algún directorio y guardas la dirección , luego con un artificio(separar las direcciones con algun identificador) puedes guardar varias direcciones en un solo campo , para no tener que crear otra tabla , y el acceso sea mas rápido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para persistir mas de una imagen podrias crear una tabla separada la cual vinculas al registro de la otra creando una relacion uno a muchos

Algo como ser

```
Formulario (tabla)
   FormularioId  PK
   otros campos

Imagenes (tabla)
   ImagenId  PK
   FormularioId  FK
   Image  (campo image o varbinary)
```

Entonces podrias tener una lista de imagenes insertando un registro en la tabla `Formulario` y N registro como imagenes tengas en la lista en la tabla `Imagenes`

PK = primary key

FK = foreign key, es la columna de relacion entre las tablas